# Python script to move matching images to separate folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, glob

I made a python script using glob (https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) this script matches JPG image with its matching XML annotation and moves it to a different folder (for example I have 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 1.xml, 3.xml) then it moves (1.jpg,1.xml and 3.jpg,3.xml) to a new folder. 2.jpg is not moved because there no xml matching this image

```
import os
import glob
import os.path
import shutil

path = os.getcwd()
j=0


os.chdir("path\\to\\folder\\")   
os.mkdir("image_with_xml")     # create a new folder
newpath =  "path\\to\\folder\\"+"image_with_xml" 

while j < len(glob.glob(path+"\\*"))-1:  
    a=glob.glob(path+"\\*")[j]

    b=glob.glob(path+"\\*")[j+1]


    print(a)
    a1 = os.path.splitext(a)[0]
    b1 = os.path.splitext(b)[0]


    if a1==b1:
        j=j+2
        shutil.move(a,newpath)   # move image to new path.
        shutil.move(b,newpath)   # move image to new path.
    else:
        j=j+1
```

The above code works well for moving a few, but not all images to new folder, in order to move the remaining images I have to create new folder inside the script then the remaining images are moved there(For example: Lets say I have 100 jpg with 100 matching XML then the first time I run this script only 62 are moved to new folder, the second time I run the script with different folder name the remaining 38 are moved to next folder). How do I modify script such that all images with matching XML are moved to one folder?

Comment: It seems like you're expecting e.g. `4.jpg` and `4.xml` to be next to each other in the glob result list, but this is not the case.

Comment: Also, this code is incredibly inefficient.  You're calling `glob.glob()` once in the while loop condition, but then you call it again, _twice!_, each time through the loop!

Comment: I am using the (if a1==b1) here I assume xml and jpg are next to each other (like 4.jpg, 4.xml,5.jpg,6.jpg,6.xml where 4 are next to each other), however, if they are not close to each other I have (else j=J+1) wherein it skips one image (so in above example it will skip 5 but take 6)

Comment: But the results could be `4.xml,6.jpg,5.xml,4.jpg,6.xml,5.jpg` in which case none of the matching numbers are adjacent.  The results of `glob()` _are not sorted_.

Comment: I see it is messing up due to way its processed in the script any way I can make it work for 4.xml,6.jpg,5.xml,4.jpg,6.xml,5.jpg format

Comment: Call `glob.glob()` _once_, save the results in a list, sort the list, then loop through that list, instead of calling glob over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do the job. I created two lists, one of the xmls, one of the jpgs. Then I check, whether a filename exists in both lists. If yes: move!

For readability, I added a new function to create the lists.

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

def remove_ext(list_of_pathnames):
    """
    removes the extension from each filename
    """
    return [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in list_of_pathnames]

path = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("path\\to\\folder\\")   
os.mkdir("image_with_xml")     # create a new folder
newpath = os.path.join("path\\to\\folder\\","image_with_xml") # made it os independent... 

list_of_jpgs = glob.glob(path+"\\*.jpg")
list_of_xmls = glob.glob(path+"\\*.xml")

print(list_of_jpgs, "\n\n", list_of_xmls) #remove

jpgs_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_jpgs)
xmls_without_extension = remove_ext(list_of_xmls)

print(jpgs_without_extension, "\n\n", xmls_without_extension) #remove

for filename in jpgs_without_extension:
    if filename in xmls_without_extension:
        print("moving", filename) #remove
        shutil.move(filename + '.jpg'), newpath)   # move image to new path.
        shutil.move(filename + '.xml'), newpath)   # move image to new path.
```

Comment: It is showing the following error, note that i have Structure1-(1)jpg file with matching xml at this location 
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ajinkya Bobade\\Desktop\\Structure2\\Structure1-(1)\\jpg'

Comment: file name creation for moving the files was damaged - should be fixed now.

Comment: its working properly till here """print(jpgs_without_extension, "\n\n", xmls_without_extension) #remove""" i.e it is listing all xml and all jps without extentions correctly, however shutil.move(filename + '.jpg'), newpath)   # move image to new path.
        shutil.move(filename + '.xml'), newpath)   # move image to new path. moves only one image in new folder

Comment: worked!! I was misspelling the correct extention for jpg